# socket.io not listening to global event

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I'm digging through Socket.io docs and still am unable to figure out why `io.sockets.on` is not working. I have tried using `io.on`, but without success.

On the client, I simply listen to the events `socket.on(ROUND_START/ROUND_END)`

This client listener is working, however, the server one - `io.sockets.on(ROUND_START...` - is not.

**Server**

```
/**
 * Handle  Game phases
 */
const NEXT_GAME_TIMEOUT = 5000;
const END_GAME_TIMEOUT = 10000;
const FULL_GAME_TIMEOUT = END_GAME_TIMEOUT + NEXT_GAME_TIMEOUT;
const ROUND_START = "ROUND_START";
const ROUND_END = "ROUND_END";

setInterval(() => {
  io.sockets.emit(ROUND_START);
}, FULL_GAME_TIMEOUT);

// Not working
io.sockets.on(ROUND_START, () => {
  console.log("ROUND STARTED")

  setTimeout(() => {
    io.sockets.emit(ROUND_END);
  }, END_GAME_TIMEOUT)
});

io.sockets.on(ROUND_END, () => {
  console.log("ROUND ENDED")

  setTimeout(() => {
    io.sockets.emit(ROUND_START);
  }, NEXT_GAME_TIMEOUT)
});
```

The idea for not sending anything related to round start from the client is because rounds have to be synchronized across sockets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey I think I misunderstood your question. If I understand correctly you wanted to catch the event that you sent from the server to the client on the server. you might want to look into the node event emitter instead, and then from that event send the update to the client. This person might have a solution to your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667378/socket-emit-event-to-server-from-server

Answer (score 0):

I usually attach the when the socket connect to the server. I got this working with chat example at https://socket.io/get-started/chat

full server config

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

const NEXT_GAME_TIMEOUT = 5000;
const END_GAME_TIMEOUT = 10000;
const FULL_GAME_TIMEOUT = END_GAME_TIMEOUT + NEXT_GAME_TIMEOUT;
const ROUND_START = "ROUND_START";
const ROUND_END = "ROUND_END";

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("user connected!!!");
    socket.on(ROUND_START, () => {
        console.log("ROUND STARTED")

        setTimeout(() => {
        io.sockets.emit(ROUND_END);
        }, END_GAME_TIMEOUT)
    });

    socket.on(ROUND_END, () => {
        console.log("ROUND ENDED")

        setTimeout(() => {
        io.sockets.emit(ROUND_START);
        }, NEXT_GAME_TIMEOUT)
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may be missing something, but The problem with this example, though, is that it’ll add a new timeout to the event queue as soon as a new round starts as many times as there connections. 2 different sockets will emit globally ROUND_START. Which means the amount of timeouts will grow exponentially with each round start and end.

Comment: That is true, but that would also be true in your example. Your client probably shouldn't control that information. I don't know enough about your game to make a final call on how to implement it, but maybe that information should be controlled by the server. If the round is closed early for any reason then the client can send that information. I tried to solve the code problem in your example, I can't fix the logical flow problem without more information :)