# Sending and getting data with socket io for two instructions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to find a way to emit from my client an instruction to the server which is inside a JSON object.
Here's my problem, my server receive my first instruction. But my second instruction 'deleteFile' is inside a json object,and the server never received this second instruction. 
I would like to know if this is possible, and if i'm doing it in the wrong way.
I want to do something like this:

Client: I emit 'instruction' with my var "message"

```
service.deleteFile = function (peer, filename, callback) {                 
  if (! LoginService.connected || ! LoginService.socket) {
    console.log("deleteFile : not connected to server");
    callback("no server");

  var message = {
    message : 'deleteFile',
    dest_list : _.flattenDeep([peer]),
    filename : filename,
  };

  LoginService.socket.emit('instruction',(message));
  console.log("service.deleteFile : " , message);
  callback(200);

};
```

And on server app.js for 'instruction':

```
socket.on('instruction', function(jsonMessage){
var dest_list = jsonMessage.dest_list;
var message = jsonMessage.message;
var filename = jsonMessage.filename;

var user_id = dest_list;
var instruction = {
  message : message,
  user_id : user_id,
  filename : filename,
};

if (dest_list.length){
  for (var i = 0; i < dest_list.length; i++) {
    var user_id = dest_list[i].toLowerCase();
    if (user_id in socket_clients){
      var socketId = socket_clients[user_id].socketId;
    socket.broadcast.to(socketId).emit('instruction', instruction);
    console.log(instruction); //print "{message:'deleteFile', user_id: ['emitter'], filename: 'thegoodfile'}
    }
    else{
      console.log("Error", user_id);
    }
  }
} else{
    console.log("Error");
} });
```

Then on server app.js for 'deleteFile'(this instruction is inside my JSON object emited from client):

```
 socket.on('deleteFile', function(jsonMessage) {
console.log("Test message"); };
```

I think my server don't understand my instruction 'deleteFile', but I don't find a way to tell him that it is an instruction.
Tell me if I missed some informations.
Thank you if you can help.

Comment: The code you show never `.emit('deleteFile', ...)`, whereas you're listening on this `'deleteFile'` command to print `"Test message"`. If `socket.broadcast.to(socketId)` is a valid socket, I guess you should replace the `emit` part with `.emit(instruction.message, instruction)` (so that `'deleteFile'`'s listener is called).

Comment: You are right, i think my problem is on my 'socket.broadcast.to'.
It is not working also with '.emit('deleteFile', instruction)'. So I'll search what is my problem with this socket.
Thank you @StockOverflaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution with this post: [socket, emit event to server from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667378/socket-emit-event-to-server-from-server)

I can't send from my server to himself with 'broadcast'. From socket.io doc:

```
 // sending to all clients except sender
socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');
```

It was written ..

So I used Event handler in Node (doc: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) and it works.